# Bouncing Slide Menu with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I'm new to Jquery and fairly new to HTML/CSS, but because I'm the type that learns through hands-on experience, I've been building a practice website while I learn new things, and have been experimenting with elements I'd like to eventually implement on a genuine site.

I've been trying to build a proper slide menu that activates when the cursor is hovered over the menu items. I've managed to get the menus to slide out, but if I move my cursor down into the slid-out menu, the whole thing starts bouncing! I've tried utilizing .stop() but then it flashes!

I've found questions on here and other sites from people with very similar (if not identical) issues, but I think I'm not understanding any of the answers that worked for them. I need visuals, and answers like "insert an if () {} statement" confuses me because I'm not sure where to put it. If I go by what my source material instructs me to do (put a check/if statement in the bottom function) it just seems to break the code and then the menus don't even slide out.

It has been very frustrating, and when I get too frustrated (like after six hours) I can't think as well about a solution, so if someone could help me find errors in my code or give me a fairly detailed explanation of what I could do to fix this bouncing problem, and how it started, I would really appreciate it.

I've attached the JQ, HTML, & CSS. Thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dropdown').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).children(".sub-menu").slideDown(200);
    },
    function() {
        $(this).children(".sub-menu").slideUp(200);
    }
);

});
```

```css
nav {
  background-color: #000000;
  padding:10px 0;
  text-align:center;
}

nav li {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: inline;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

nav a {
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover,
nav a:focus,
nav a:active {
  color: #ff0000;
}

nav ul li {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}

nav li ul {
  background-color:#000000;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:50px;
  width:200px;
}

nav li li a {
  position:relative;
  font-size:25px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display:block;
}

ul.sub-menu {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li><a href=""><b>Home</b></a></li>
  <li><a href="">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Inspiration</a></li>

  <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Find</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="">Ebooks</a></li>
      <li><a href="">PDFs</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>  

  <li><a href="">News</a></li>

  <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Contact Us</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="">E-mail List</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Extras</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="">Coming Soon</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a space between your `<li>` elements and the dropdown menu ([You can see it here](https://jsfiddle.net/8g48k77c/)).
Just remove / move it.

I did

```
nav {
  [...]
  // padding: 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav li {
  [...]
  // padding: 0 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dropdown').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).children(".sub-menu").slideDown(200);
    },
    function() {
        $(this).children(".sub-menu").slideUp(200);
    }
);

});
```

```css
nav {
  background-color: #000000;
  padding: 0;
  text-align:center;
}

nav li {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

nav a {
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover,
nav a:focus,
nav a:active {
  color: #ff0000;
}

nav ul li {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}

nav li ul {
  background-color:#000000;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:50px;
  width:200px;
}

nav li li a {
  position:relative;
  font-size:25px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display:block;
}

ul.sub-menu {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li><a href=""><b>Home</b></a></li>
  <li><a href="">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Inspiration</a></li>

  <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Find</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="">Ebooks</a></li>
      <li><a href="">PDFs</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>  

  <li><a href="">News</a></li>

  <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Contact Us</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="">E-mail List</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Extras</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="">Coming Soon</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: What the hell? That was it? The CSS? For goodness' sake. Well, it fixed my problem. Thanks, Robiseb.

Answer (score 0):

Change css in `nav li ul` where `top:50px` to `padding-top:23px`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dropdown').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).children(".sub-menu").slideDown(200);
    },
    function() {
        $(this).children(".sub-menu").slideUp(200);
    }
);

});
```

```css
nav {
  background-color: #000000;
  padding:10px 0;
  text-align:center;
}

nav li {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: inline;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

nav a {
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover,
nav a:focus,
nav a:active {
  color: #ff0000;
}

nav ul li {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}

nav li ul {
  background-color:#000000;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  padding-top:23px;
  width:200px;
}

nav li li a {
  position:relative;
  font-size:25px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0`;
  display:block;
}

ul.sub-menu {
    display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li><a href=""><b>Home</b></a></li>
  <li><a href="">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Inspiration</a></li>

  <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Find</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="">Ebooks</a></li>
      <li><a href="">PDFs</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>  

  <li><a href="">News</a></li>

  <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Contact Us</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="">E-mail List</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Extras</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="">Coming Soon</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```